# identifying if pdf content is in the last page

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, xhtml2pdf

knowing that

```
<pdf:pagenumber />
```

gives the current page number, while

```
<pdf:pagecount />
```

gives the total page count.

I want to acquire these values and be able to compare it using django if/else like this

```
{% ifequal "<pdf:pagenumber />"  "<pdf:pagecount />" %}
    last page content
{% endifequal %}
```

how would I be able to compare these two?

also tried

```
<pdf:nexttemplate name="lastpage"/>
```

but it's not appropriate to my dynamic setup
if only there is "lasttemplate" though

Comment: I have same problem, need use a diferente template to last page, but next template dont work for this.

Answer (score 0):

Can create variable for current page and last page. You can compare later.

```
{% with CurrentPage="<pdf:pagenumber />" LastPage="<pdf:pagecount />" %}     
    {% if CurrentPage.value == LastPage.value %}
        You are on the last page
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```